# Django Admin relations between tables: save database updates in several tables

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django admin for managing my data.

I have a `Users`, `Groups` and `Domains` tables.
`Users` table has many to many relationship with `Groups` and `Domains` tables.
`Domains` table has one to many relationship with `Groups` table.
and when I save the User data through admin I also need some addtional database updates in  the `users_group` and the `users_domains` table.

How do I do this? Where do I put the code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [InlineModels](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). They allow you to edit related models in the same page as the parent model. If you are looking for greater control than this, you can override the ModelAdmin [save methods](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods).

Also, always check out the [Manual](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/) when you need something. It really is quite good.

Comment: Paolo:
Looks like I need to override the save method.
As I mentioned before I need to update a couple of database tables... and let rest of the operations perform as usual. How do I do that.
Thanks

Comment: Look in the example in the documentation. Just define a function named save_model in the AdminModel class and do what you need in there.

Comment: I was just playing around with save_model.
Looks like whatever statements put in here are executed and the save operation follows even if I do not explicitly call save(). Is this the right behavior. I am not able to find any further documentation on the django website. Thanks.

Comment: This is the right behavior. Are you trying to abort the save or something? I do not think that is possible without some hacking around.

Comment: When I save the save_model is executed before the POST and the GET. Is there a way to execute the save_model after the POST and before the GET.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to update other database tables is to perform the necessary get and save operations.  However, if you have a many-to-many relationship, by default, both sides of the relationship are accessible from a `<lower_case_model_name>_set` parameter.  That is, `user.group_set.all()` will give you all Group objects associated with a user, while `group.user_set.all()` will give you all User objects associated with a group.  So if you override the save method (or register a signal listener--whichever option sounds stylistically more pleasing), try:

```
for group in user.group_set.all():
    #play with group object
    ....
    group.save()
```